# Drawing contours from label_image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, scikit-image

I have a `label_image` array and I am deriving the outlines/boundaries of the objects on that array. Currently I am doing that by getting all unique labels, iterating over them and then find the contours of each object. Like in the loop below, where I am populating a `dict` with keys the label and values the contours

```
import cv2
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


def extract_borders(label_image):
    labels = np.unique(label_image[label_image > 0])
    d = {}
    for label in labels:
        y = label_image == label
        y = y * 255
        y = y.astype('uint8')
        contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(y, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
        contours = np.squeeze(contours)
        d[label] = contours.tolist()
    df = pd.DataFrame([d]).T
    df = df.reset_index()
    df.columns = ['label', 'coords']
    return df


if __name__ == "__main__":
    label_img = np.array([
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    ])

    res = extract_borders(label_img)
    print(res)
```

When `labels` are thousands this can be a real bottleneck. Is there a more efficient way to do this please? Maybe there is a function I am not aware of... I want to be able to assign the label to the corresponding contours.

The code above prints:

```
   label                                             coords
0      1                   [[5, 6], [5, 9], [9, 9], [9, 6]]
1      2  [[3, 3], [3, 12], [11, 12], [11, 10], [5, 10],...
2      3  [[12, 5], [11, 6], [10, 6], [10, 9], [11, 9], ...
3      4  [[12, 3], [12, 4], [14, 4], [15, 5], [15, 10],...
```

Comment: [`cv2.drawContours`](https://docs..org/master/d4/d73/tutorial_py_contours_begin.html)?

Comment: On the other hand, it might be easier to mask the object with different colors based on the labels.

Comment: @QuangHoang: Thanks, I guess I didnt put the best title in this post. The problem is not how to draw the contours but how to associate the contours with the correct label

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. Can you provide an input image please, along with some runnable code including `import` statements? Thank you.

Comment: @Mark, thanks, I added some code, hope that helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DIPlib library has a function to extract the chain code for each object in the image. It does require, however, that each object is connected (the pixels with the same label must form a connected component). Using Mark's large example image, this takes computation time from 154.8s to 0.781s, 200 times faster. And most of that time, I think, is dedicated to converting the chain code into a polygon, into a numpy array, into a list, and finally into a pandas table. Lots of conversions...

One thing to note: the chain codes returned by `dip.GetImageChainCodes` are as you'd expect: they trace the outer pixels of each object. However, [converting these to a polygon](https://diplib.github.io/diplib-docs/structdip_1_1ChainCode.html#a078077d7d65b44786245a6c5b6d83ee6) does something different: the polygon doesn't link the outer pixels, but goes *around* them, following the "crack" between the pixels. And it cuts pixel corners doing so. This leads to a polygon that much better describes the actual object, its area is exactly half a pixel smaller than the number of pixels in the object, and its length is much closer to the perimeter of the underlying object (before discretizing it into a set of pixels). This idea comes from [Steve Eddins at the MathWorks](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2011/10/04/binary-image-convex-hull-algorithm-notes/).

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import diplib as dip
import cv2
import time

def extract_borders(label_image):
    labels = np.unique(label_image[label_image > 0])
    d = {}
    for label in labels:
        y = label_image == label
        y = y * 255
        y = y.astype('uint8')
        contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(y, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
        contours = np.squeeze(contours)
        d[label] = contours.tolist()
    df = pd.DataFrame([d]).T
    df = df.reset_index()
    df.columns = ['label', 'coords']
    return df

def extract_borders_dip(label_image):
    cc = dip.GetImageChainCodes(label_img) # input must be an unsigned integer type
    d = {}
    for c in cc:
        d[c.objectID] = np.array(c.Polygon()).tolist()
    df = pd.DataFrame([d]).T
    df = df.reset_index()
    df.columns = ['label', 'coords']
    return df

if __name__ == "__main__":
    label_img = np.arange(2500, dtype=np.uint16).reshape((50,50))
    label_img = cv2.resize(label_img, (4000,4000), interpolation=cv2.INTER_NEAREST)
    start = time.process_time()
    res = extract_borders(label_img)
    print('OP code:', time.process_time() - start)
    print(res)
    start = time.process_time()
    res = extract_borders_dip(label_img)
    print('DIPlib code: ', time.process_time() - start)
    print(res)
```

Comment: Nice work - not even worth parallelising at that sort of performance!

Comment: Really impressive Cris!! Many thanks. It is a shame for me that `GetImageChainCodes` needs an array of type either `uint8` or `uint16` since I might have more that 65535(!!!) unique labels and the function crashes when `uint32` is passed in. I guess there is no way around that, is it?....If I understand well, I can remove any redundant points from the contours with `np.array(c.Polygon().Simplify())`. Some coords that `np.array(c.Polygon())` returns are increased or decreased by 0.5. Is there a fix for this please? Many thanks again

Comment: @Aenaon: it should work with 32-bit ints. DIPlib’s labeling routine always returns uint32, so this has been tested extensively. What OS are you on? Could you please submit a ticket with a [mre] at the [project’s issue tracker](https://github.com/DIPlib/diplib/issues)?

Comment: @Aenaon: Regarding “Some coords [...] are increased or decreased by 0.5”: This is explained in the answer. The polygon surrounds the pixels in the object, following the line between pixels (and pixel centers are at integer locations). There are many advantages to this for quantification. You can convert the chain codes to polygons quite simply yourself, if you want something different. [This post on my blog](https://www.crisluengo.net/archives/324) shows how (at the bottom).

Comment: Many thanks Cris, you have also helped me on another occasion recently

Answer (score 3):

I had a try as follows with multiprocessing and got a 2.5x speedup using 6 CPUs:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from multiprocessing import Pool, cpu_count, freeze_support
from functools import partial
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import cv2
import os

def worker(labels, label_image):
    """One worker started per CPU. Receives the label image once and a list of the labels to look for."""
    pid = os.getpid()
    print(f'Worker pid: {pid}, processing {len(labels)} labels')
    d = {}
    for label in labels:
        y = label_image == label
        y = y * 255
        y = y.astype('uint8')
        contours, _ = cv2.findContours(y, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
        contours = np.squeeze(contours)
        d[label] = contours.tolist()
    return d

if __name__ == '__main__':

    freeze_support()

    # Synthesize label image: 2500 labels arranged as 50x50 image, then scaled up to some realistic size
    label_image = np.arange(2500, dtype=np.uint16).reshape((50,50))
    label_image = cv2.resize(label_image, (4000,4000), interpolation=cv2.INTER_NEAREST)

    # Get number of cores and split labels across that many workers
    processes = cpu_count()

    # UNCOMMENT FOLLOWING LINE FOR SINGLE CPU
    # processes = 1
    print(f'Using {processes} processes')

    labels = np.unique(label_image[label_image > 0])
    print(f'Unique labels detected: {labels}')

    # Chunk up the labels across the processes
    chunks = np.array_split(labels, processes)

    # Map the labels across the processes
    with Pool(processes=processes) as pool:
        result = pool.map(partial(worker, label_image=label_image), chunks)

    #print(result)
```

**Sample Output with 12 cores**

```
Using 12 processes
Unique labels detected: [   1    2    3 ... 2497 2498 2499]
Worker pid: 76884, processing 209 labels
Worker pid: 76886, processing 209 labels
Worker pid: 76885, processing 209 labels
Worker pid: 76888, processing 208 labels
Worker pid: 76887, processing 208 labels
Worker pid: 76889, processing 208 labels
Worker pid: 76890, processing 208 labels
Worker pid: 76893, processing 208 labels
Worker pid: 76891, processing 208 labels
Worker pid: 76892, processing 208 labels
Worker pid: 76895, processing 208 labels
Worker pid: 76894, processing 208 labels
```

Comment: Nice example image, didn't suspect OP's code would take that much time, or I would have made it smaller for my test... ;)  (+1)

Comment: Thanks Mark, nice one. I also gave `multiprocessing` a go, slightly different way than yours. I used `threads`with this import statement `from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool`. Mine runs does your `label_image` in 63secs, but your code does it a bit faster, 58secs