# OpenCV find contours based on the pixel value

Tags: python, opencv

I have an image as shown and using OpenCV I want to find the contours based on the color of each of the contours. The pixel values in this image are 0,1 and 2.

**Image**

What I am looking for is to get 2 yellow contours, 1 big green contour and 1 small green contour inside the second yellow contour on right

Opencv gives me just two contours here. What is the best way to achieve it?

**My code so far:**

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

img = cv.imread("seg_img.png",cv.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

# find contour
contours, _ = cv.findContours(image =img, mode = cv.RETR_TREE,method = cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# loop through the contours and find area of each contour
for i,cnt in enumerate(contours):
   print(cv.contourArea(cnt))
```

**Pixel values**

```
np.unique(img)
2
```

Comment: According to the documentation at https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gadf1ad6a0b82947fa1fe3c3d497f260e0, findContours is designed for **binary images**. So threshold each color (or id number) one at a time and get the contours. Do that for each color and draw your contours on the same black background image. Use RETR_EXTERNAL to get the outer contours of each thresholded image. You should get 4 contours, 2 for the yellow and 2 for the green.

Comment: @fmw42 Not sure what do you mean by threshold each color? Is there a way to just threshold specific color in opencv?

Comment: i think first i need a HSV for the image and then mask one color at a time and then apply threshold to find conturs for each color

Comment: There's a multiprocessing version here that you could simplify... https://stackoverflow.com/a/64391237/2836621

Comment: For thresholding on color, see cv2.inRange() at https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga48af0ab51e36436c5d04340e036ce981